# Schedule event is showing unauthorized in AWS serverless?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless

I have using schedule property in event to create trigger in the lambda function, have provided the full access in the AWS, but still facing unauthorized error while deploying the stack. find the below code for AWS lambda and suggest the solution to debug this issue.

```
ErecruitDBToS3LambdaFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: !Sub ${Environment}-${Application}-db-s3-store-${EntityName}-event
      Description: A Lambda function that read updated data from eRecruit DB into S3Bucket.
      Runtime: nodejs14.x
      Timeout: 60
      MemorySize: 128
      Handler: !Sub src/handlers/${EntityName}/eRecruitDBS3.eventHandler
      Layers:
        - !Ref ACFLayer
      Policies:
        - AWSLambdaRole
        - AWSLambdaExecute
        - AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole
        - AmazonS3FullAccess
        - AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole
        - AmazonEventBridgeFullAccess
        - SSMParameterReadPolicy:
            ParameterName: 'acf/*'
        - DynamoDBCrudPolicy:
            TableName: "*"
        - Statement:
            Effect: "Allow"
            Action: "events:*"
            Resource: "arn:aws:events:*:*:*"
      Environment:
        Variables:
          ConnectorName: !Ref ConnectorName
          EntityName: !Ref EntityName
          ErecruitTable: !Ref ErecruitEngagementDefinitionTable
          LogLevel: !Ref LogLevel
          S3BucketName: !Ref S3BucketName
          ErecruitDBSSMPath: !Ref ErecruitDBSSMPath
      VpcConfig:
        SecurityGroupIds:
          - sg-042efcebb92b0573d
        SubnetIds:
          - subnet-0a3a8e3a5465d1fce
          - subnet-016b565821a02dd54
          - subnet-01c21fa0b46e76b1a
      Tags:
        Environment: !Ref Environment
        Application: !Ref Application
        Owner: !Ref Owner
        OwnerContact: !Ref OwnerContact
        CodePath: !Ref CodePath
      Events: !Ref CWSchedule
        
  CWSchedule:
    Type: Schedule
    Properties:
      Schedule: 'rate(5 minutes)'
      Name: TestSchedule
      Description: test schedule
      Enabled: false

  ErecruitDBToS3LambdaFunctionPermission:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
    Properties:
      FunctionName: !GetAtt ErecruitDBToS3LambdaFunction.Arn
      Action: lambda:InvokeFunction
      Principal: events.amazonaws.com
```

Comment: AWS does not just say "unauthorized error", it always tells you what entity is not allowed to perform what action.

Comment: yes, its showing user is not authorized to perform the event:putRule